# An easier method to extract the last four elements of a vector in DolphinDB?

Tags: vector, arraylist, dolphindb

I want to extract the last four elements of a vector in DolphinDB. For example:

```
v=1..9
v[5:9]
```

Output:

[image]

I'd like to find an easier method to achieve this, so I tried the following method:

```
l=size(v)
v[l-4:l]
```

But the result is not as expected. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to operator precedence. You need to add parentheses around `1-4`:

```
l=size(v)
v[(l-4):l]
```

Or you can try a more efficient method:

```
v.tail(4)
```